# Remove duplicate in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, duplicates

I have a collection with the field called "contact_id".
In my collection I have duplicate registers with this key.

How can I remove duplicates, resulting in just one register?

I already tried:

```
db.PersonDuplicate.ensureIndex({"contact_id": 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

But did not work, because the function `dropDups` is no longer available in MongoDB 3.x

I'm using 3.2

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, dropDups is gone for good. But you can definitely achieve your goal with little bit effort.

You need to first find all duplicate rows and then remove all except first.

```
db.dups.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$contact_id", dups:{$push:"$_id"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
{$match:{count: {$gt: 1}}}
]).forEach(function(doc){
  doc.dups.shift();
  db.dups.remove({_id : {$in: doc.dups}});
});
```

As you see `doc.dups.shift()` will remove first **_id** from array and then remove all documents with remaining _ids in dups array.

script above will remove all duplicate documents.

Comment: Hi. Partial worked.
When I put in a small collection works fine. 
But when I execute in a big collection the databases "lock" and others query goes to timeout.

Comment: Well, this is expected especially in very large collections. MongoDB aggregation pipeline is limited to 100MB RAM usage. See https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/. again your question didn't mentioned anything about your collection size. This solution gives you idea how to solve a problem and is not covering all edge cases. So you'll need to put some efforts too.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'll search about this.

Comment: For large collections, you may need to use the [Bulk Write Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/) feature.

Comment: I just want to add that you can group by multiple keys by listing them and you can list whole document (not only keys you group by) for more context. This is how: [{$group: {_id: ["$key1", "$key12", "$key42"], dups: {$push: "$$ROOT"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}]

Answer (score 5):

this is a good pattern for mongod 3+ that also ensures that you will not run our of memory which can happen with really big collections. You can save this to a dedup.js file, customize it, and run it against your desired database with: mongo localhost:27017/YOURDB dedup.js

```
var duplicates = [];

db.runCommand(
  {aggregate: "YOURCOLLECTION",
    pipeline: [
      { $group: { _id: { DUPEFIELD: "$DUPEFIELD"}, dups: { "$addToSet": "$_id" }, count: { "$sum": 1 } }},
      { $match: { count: { "$gt": 1 }}}
    ],
    allowDiskUse: true }
)
.result
.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.dups.shift();
    doc.dups.forEach(function(dupId){ duplicates.push(dupId); })
})
printjson(duplicates); //optional print the list of duplicates to be removed

db.YOURCOLLECTION.remove({_id:{$in:duplicates}});
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use an [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#out-aggregation) stage to remove duplicates from a collection by replacing the content of the collection with only one occurrence per duplicate.

For instance, to only keep one element per value of `x`:

```
// > db.collection.find()
//     { "x" : "a", "y" : 27 }
//     { "x" : "a", "y" : 4  }
//     { "x" : "b", "y" : 12 }
db.collection.aggregate(
  { $group: { _id: "$x", onlyOne: { $first: "$$ROOT" } } },
  { $replaceWith: "$onlyOne" }, // prior to 4.2: { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$onlyOne" } }
  { $out: "collection" }
)
// > db.collection.find()
//     { "x" : "a", "y" : 27 }
//     { "x" : "b", "y" : 12 }
```

This:

- `$group`s documents by the field defining what a duplicate is (here `x`) and accumulates grouped documents by only keeping one (the `$first` found) and giving it the value [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#out-aggregation), which is the document itself. At the end of this stage, we have something like:

  ```
  { "_id" : "a", "onlyOne" : { "x" : "a", "y" : 27 } }
  { "_id" : "b", "onlyOne" : { "x" : "b", "y" : 12 } }
  ```
- [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/index.html) all existing fields in the input document with the content of the `onlyOne` field we've created in the `$group` stage, in order to find the original format back. At the end of this stage, we have something like:

  ```
  { "x" : "a", "y" : 27 }
  { "x" : "b", "y" : 12 }
  ```

  `$replaceWith` is only available starting in `Mongo 4.2`. With prior versions, we can use [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) instead:

  ```
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$onlyOne" } }
  ```
- [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#out-aggregation) inserts the result of the aggregation pipeline in the same collection. Note that `$out` conveniently replaces the content of the specified collection, making this solution possible.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it be a good try to create a tmpColection, create unique index, then copy data from source, and last step will be swap names?

Other idea, I had is to get doubled indexes into array (using aggregation) and then loop thru calling the remove() method with the justOne parameter set to true or 1.

```
 var itemsToDelete = db.PersonDuplicate.aggregate([
{$group: { _id:"$_id", count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match: {count: {$gt:1}}},
{$group: { _id:1, ids:{$addToSet:"$_id"}}}
])
```

and make a loop thru ids array
makes this sense for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach:

1. Take the mongo dump of the particular collection.
2. Clear that collection
3. Add a unique key index
4. Restore the dump using mongorestore.